# ActiveRecord - Query with Condition of Last Element in Association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Trying to do a sort of complex query in ActiveRecord right now. Not sure if it's possible to do entirely in ActiveRecord (i.e. without just filtering intermediate results in Rails). I'd like to do as much manipulation as possible in the database.

I have a `PullRequest` and `Release` model with a many-many relationship. There exist fields on the `Release` model `is_rollback`(boolean) and `ended_at` (datetime). I am trying to find all `pull_requests` for which their `releases` association 1) is nonempty and 2) ends with a `release` that has `is_rollback = true` when the `releases` are ordered by `ended_at`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
PullRequest
  .joins(:releases) # filter pull requests with empty release associations
  .having('releases.is_rollback = true AND releases.ended_at = MAX(releases.ended_at)') # where latest release is a rollback
  .group('pull_requests.id, releases.ended_at, releases.is_rollback') # necessary with 'having'
```

The `having` clause is not working as expected though and the query is still returning pull requests whose latest release is not a rollback. Not hugely experienced with complex SQL queries so any help is appreciated. I'm using Rails 4, PostgreSQL db.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the definition of `nonempty`? You could add your models (and migrations), and the RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure it out - here is the working query:

```
pull_requests
  .joins(:releases).distinct
  .group('releases.ended_at, pull_requests.id, releases.id')
  .having('releases.ended_at IN (SELECT MAX(releases.ended_at))')
  .where('releases.is_rollback = true')
```

Thanks.